# how to connect to two wireless network

Tags: wireless, networking

I have two hotspot/wireless network at my home,
and I have 2 wireless adapter in my laptop,

can I connect to 2 wireless network and use both to connect to internet for increasing internet access speed?

big thanks..

Xgaptek.tk

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can but you need to have two different IP schemes like 192.168.0.xxx and 192.168.1.xxx.  Once you do that, you need to have both connections bridged.